# OnConnected Task not firing when upgrading to SignalR 1.0.0 alpha2

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have just recently tried to upgrade to signalR 1.0.0 Alpha2.  I went through the wiki, changed what I thought I needed to change plus made sure the assembly was all loaded with the new files.  Here is my js:

```
$(function () {
    var Chat = $.connection.ChatHub;
    ...
    $.connection.hub.start(
    .done(function(){ alert("Now connected!"); })
    .fail(function(){ alert("Could not Connect!"); });
});
```

Here is my hub class:

```````````````````````````````````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using MyProject.Domain.Abstract;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Security;
using MyProject.Domain.Entities;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using MyProject.Domain.Concrete;
using MyProject.Domain.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Web.RealTime
{
    public class ChatMessage
    {
        public string ChatId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }
        public string Major { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
   [HubName("ChatHub")]
    public class Chat : Hub
    {
        //Initialize Repoisotries 
        private IProfileRepository profileRepository;
        private ISiteDataRepository siteDataRepository;
        private IChatRepository chatRepository;
        private IOnlineUserRepository onlineUserRepository;
        private IRecentActivityRepository recentActivityRepository;


        MembershipUser MainUser = Membership.GetUser();
        UserProfile MainProfile;
        //In memory objects
        //public static Dictionary<Guid, List<string>> onlineUsers = new Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>();


        //Constructor Injection for profile repository and site data repository
        public Chat(IProfileRepository repo, ISiteDataRepository siteRepo, IChatRepository chatRepo, IOnlineUserRepository onlineUserRepo, IRecentActivityRepository recentActivityRepo)
        {            
            profileRepository = repo;
            siteDataRepository = siteRepo;
            chatRepository = chatRepo;
            onlineUserRepository = onlineUserRepo;
            MainProfile = profileRepository.GetProfile((Guid)MainUser.ProviderUserKey);
            recentActivityRepository = recentActivityRepo;
        }



        public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {

            disconnectUser();
            List<ContactItem> contacts = profileRepository.GetFollowedOnlineContacts(MainProfile.UserId);
            foreach (ContactItem ci in contacts)
            {
                Clients.Group(Convert.ToString(ci.ChatId)).onlineUserHandler(Convert.ToString(MainProfile.ChatId), false);
            }
            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }
        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            connectUser();
            List<ContactItem> contacts = profileRepository.GetFollowedOnlineContacts(MainProfile.UserId);
            foreach (ContactItem ci in contacts)
            {
                Clients.Group(Convert.ToString(ci.ChatId)).onlineUserHandler(Convert.ToString(ci.ChatId), true);
            }
            return base.OnReconnected();
        }
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Connected``````````````````````````````````");
            connectUser();
            List<ContactItem> contacts = profileRepository.GetFollowedOnlineContacts(MainProfile.UserId);
            foreach (ContactItem ci in contacts)
            {
                Clients.Group(Convert.ToString(ci.ChatId)).onlineUserHandler(Convert.ToString(MainProfile.ChatId), true);
            }
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
        private void connectUser()
        {
            if (onlineUserRepository.ConnectUser(MainProfile.UserId, Context.ConnectionId))
            {
                Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, Convert.ToString(MainProfile.ChatId));
            }
        }
        private void disconnectUser()
        {
            onlineUserRepository.DisconnectUser(MainProfile.UserId, Context.ConnectionId);
            Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, Convert.ToString(MainProfile.ChatId));
        }





    }
}
```````````````````````````````````

On the client side, i get the alert saying im connected, but when I run a debug and put a break point in the "OnConnected" task, it never breaks there or runs anything in my hub class.  what could I be doing wrong?

This is my assembly for the new SignalR:

[image]

I used to use this in my NinjectWebCommon.cs file in the App_Start folder, but ever since I upgraded it gave me errors, so i commented out, could be the problem also but not sure because signalR.ninject doesnt seem to be working or gave me a bunch of errors:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver =  new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdGenerator), () => new MyConnectionFactory());

    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
```

Comment: I get this problem too, using an extremely simple example (basically just the OnXXXX methods and nothing else. The rest of the framework is running fine, just these OnXXX methods that won't fire.

Comment: Do you have any subscriptions? The syntax changed for alpha so you may not be subscribed to any hub methods at all. http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx

Comment: I have no subscriptions, are these required in the new release?

Comment: Nope, it was always required.

Comment: @dfowler I figured out that it was my constructor that was causing the issue because it is not being properly injected.  I read on the comments in your blog post that you are working on the new ninject update for signalr, if I take away the injection and just instantiate the classes in the hub without injecting it, will I face any ailing performance issues?  Currently my system may be only 30-50 people on at once so the load isnt huge or anything

Comment: @anthonypliu You should consider answering your own question here... I have been trawling google for details on this and turns out I had the same problem. It needs more visibility!

Comment: @Roysvork  Added the answer,  I stopped using dependancy injection because the `NinjectDependencyResolver` was built for the older version, and i believe they were working on one, but I haven't seen the new version for this yet.

Answer (score 2):

You should add in JavaScript before starting the hub reference to methods:

```
$.connection.yourhub.client.connected = function () { };
$.connection.yourhub.client.disconnected = function () { };
```

Comment: i had a barebones javascript client directly from a browser that would successfully connect but not trigger the server side connected and disconnected events.  adding these two lines made it work. strangely enough these two lines are not required in my asp.net or blackberry implementation of signalr

Comment: I was assigning my hub client callbacks inside the `$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { /* ... */ });` function.  When I moved them outside the function, such that they were bound before `$.connection.hub.start` was called, the issue was solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because I was using the non updated version of NinjectDependancyResolver, which I am not sure if they have updated it or not.  In fact, I have stopped using dependency injection into my hub classes all together because I wasn't able to get it working.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting the same problem as I was trying to inject dependencies but I hadn't set up my IOC properly.